# combining gunzip and tar commands in Solaris and AIX

Tags: unix, solaris, tar, aix, gunzip

I am running the below command to untar a file in Solaris and AIX:

```
# gunzip /opt/myfile.tar.gz | tar -xvf-
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
tar: Unexpected end-of-file while reading from the storage media.
```

What do I need to fix?

Comment: I know there are other ways to untar it..! But i want it in above way. It should work right..!?

Comment: It shouldn't work as specified because `gunzip` defaults to writing to a file, not to stdout for a pipe to read from.  `gzcat` or `gunzip -c` change that to write to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Why should this work? The default behaviour of  gunzip unpacks the file in place,  substitutes the packed file with the unpacked one and you didn't specified the nescessary command to put the uncompressed datastream to stdout. So the tar command doesn't receive anything through the pipe  to process and so you get the errormessage you have seen.

This will work:

```
gunzip -c ../myfile.tar.gz | tar -xfv -
```

This command line was tested on a Solaris 11.3 ... older variants of Solaris  may need a different sorting of the command line like

```
gunzip -c ../myfile.tar.gz | tar -xvf -
```

Comment: On macOS Sierra, the BSD `tar` will work with `tar xfv -` (no dash before the options) and with `tar -xvf -` but not `tar -xfv -` (with a dash before the options).  The `tar` syntax pre-dates the near-universal use of `-X` to indicate options; it originally only supported the options without a preceding dash.  That version expected all the options in a single cluster and used the next argument as the tar file name if the `f` appeared at all.  Some versions of `tar` accept a dash before the options and then treat `f` like the `getopt()` function would; the file name comes immediately after it.

Comment: GNU `tar` behaves basically the same as BSD `tar` in this matter — if the options start with a dash, then `-f` must be at the end of the cluster and the tar file name is either attached to the `f` or in the next argument.  These more modern versions of `tar` support multiple command line options with arguments — they are fairly conventional when the option cluster starts with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work but I I don't have a Solaris system to test it...

```
gzip -dc /opt/myfile.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```